# INSERTING Similar values in mysql but changing the date column for a number of times using a single query

Tags: php, mysql

Am working on a reservation system for more than one hotel each with more than one room type and I would like to create an availability calendar. My thinking is If I can repeat insertion of reservations details (name, check_in_date, check_out_date, hotel_name....bla bla)for the number of days one may book a room say, my check in date is 2014-12-28 and check out date is 2015-01-07, I insert repeating the values of all the other columns apart from the check_in_date which should increase upto the date before check out date, then I can use row count and subtract per day per room type to arrive at the rooms available.

I am stuck at the database...and the php code...I can not seem to get the value of an html input of date type to act as my start date

If anyone knows an easier way to achieve my availability calendar, please share with me.

Thanks and happy holidays.

Comment: Please provide examples of your code to make it easier for others to help you

Comment: <?php

 

 
 // Start date
 $date = '$_POST['check_in_date']';
 // End date
  $date = '$_POST['check_out_date']';
 
 while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
 //The code to insert into the table
 $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
 }
 
?>

Comment: what do you mean by "`then I can use row count and subtract per day per room type to arrive at the rooms available.`??" do you want to show to user, the availability(in different hotel, room type) accordingly on each day?? or something else??

Comment: Adarsh Rajput Yes I would like to show to user, the availability(in different hotels, the room type) accordingly for a period of around 14 days.

Comment: @JeffersonSankara ok.. i'll answer. but why you storing in database then. if user closed the window after seeing availability? Its better to loop from date_in to date_out, check availability and generate HTML for each day. **And also add the table's column names HERE, from which you are checking availability, to help you in better way.**

Comment: @Adarsh Rajput, The availability table has hotel_name, hotel_branch, room_type, rooms_available columns. I was hoping to get the data in the table first,  then if I would do a row count say WHERE check_in_date (2014-12-28) is the value gotten from the input type date for the check_in_date, do another query for the row count where there is a checkout to also know the rooms to be free that check in date, then add the two and subtract the results from the default value of the number of rooms per room type.

Comment: @JeffersonSankara your logic is ok, INSERT record only when user confirm in BOOKING table. here you need to check booked rooms from BOOKING table, at particular date and `room_type` by row count and subtract from `room_available` | hereafter comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it like following:

1) In HTML `input` ask user to enter the date in `YYYY-MM-DD`// I think u r doing same

2) On submit loop through `date_in` and `date_out`, check availability and display.

```
$availability="";
if( $date_in=date_create($_POST["check_in_date"]) && 
  $date_out=date_create($_POST["check_out_date"]) )
  {
    $interval = date_diff($date_in, $date_out)->format('%R%a')+1;
    for($j=0;$j<$interval;$j++){
         $date=date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
         $availability.="ON ".$date->format("Y-m-d").": ";

         //check in database and append to $availability as available...
         // ....in Hotel XXX,YYY room type AAA,BBB [as you want to display]
    }
 }
 else $availability="Enter dates correctly";

echo $availability;
```

3) if user confirm & pay then store in database with booking confirmation.

```
//code to store in database
// assuming table BOOKING (date,room_type,hotel_id)
//mentioning only required column, you may have more

$bookingDone=false;
if($confirmPayment && $date_in=date_create($_POST["check_in_date"]) && 
  $date_out=date_create($_POST["check_out_date"]) )
  {
    $interval = date_diff($date_in, $date_out)->format('%R%a')+1;

    mysqli_start_transaction($dbConnection);
    $bookingDone=true;
    for($j=0;$j<$interval;$j++){
         $date=date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));

         //insert in database, $j is dayNo. Ex. in your case 28th will be first day...

         // $sql="INSERT INTO booking VALUES ('".$date->format("Y-m-d")."','".$selected_room_type_for_day[$j]."','".$selected_hotel_for_day[$j]."');

         if(!inserted) $bookingDone=false;
    }
    if($bookingDone) mysqli_commit($dbConnection);
    else mysqli_rollback($dbConnection);
 }
 else echo "An error occured";
```

---

**query to check availability**  will be used in step 2)

```
 "SELECT count(1) as filled_room, hotel_id, room_type FROM booking WHERE date='".$date->format("Y-m-d")."' GROUP BY hotel_id,room_type;"

 "SELECT rooms_available-".$filled_room." FROM hotel_info WHERE hotel_id=".$hotel_id." AND room_type='".$room_type."';"

  //variable used in second query comes from first one & second will return available rooms
  // hotel_info table contains information about each hotels and no of rooms af perticuler type, value of `rooms_available` contains no of rooms in particular hotel.
```